# ng-model is not updating the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checkbox which bind with a ng-model:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="toggleAll(globalChecked)" ng-model="globalChecked">
```

Whereas toggleAll will grab the globalChecked value and process other logic in my controller:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(val) {
    if ($scope.objects == undefined) {
        return
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.objects.length; ++i) {
        $scope.objects[i].checked = val;
    }
}
```

However, for the firs time, when I click the checkbox, toggleAll get called but the val (or globalChecked value) is still false.

Just wonder did I miss anything here?

Comment: Which version of angular? Is the checkbox is checked initially? This should work just fine.

Comment: A JSBin/Plunker would be appreciated.

Comment: Just tried this and it works fine. How are you declaring globalChecked?  I just did $scope.globalChecked, not setting it to any value, and it worked fine.

Comment: can you send me the plunker?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't miss anything, it works fine for me. Here is a sample plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/BbVs7pEEFGTunXVkxCMj?p=preview

If it doesn't work the first time, make sure to initialize the value of the first checkbox (`ng-model="globalChecked"` in your code).

```html
  <input type='checkbox' ng-click="checkAll(toplevel)" ng-model="toplevel">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in objects">
    <input type='checkbox' ng-model="obj.checked">
  </div>
```

```js
$scope.objects = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  if (!$scope.objects[i])
    $scope.objects[i] = {checked: false};
}

$scope.checkAll = function(val){
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    console.log($scope.objects[i]);
    $scope.objects[i].checked = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, how does this not provide an answer? The question is whether the author missed anything. After testing the code in a plunker, the answer seems to be no, and that another variable may be at play.

Comment: That's an auto-generated comment based on review, but essentially telling the OP "i don't see anything wrong" is not an answer even if their question was poorly worded to imply that that does "answer" it. What you have is still a comment that should then prompt the OP to reword their question or provide more detail such that you can give a true answer to their question.